# How to exclude unwanted comparisons in two-way ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

I would like to know the way to exclude all the unwanted pairs of POST-HOC tests from the output generated from two-way ANOVA. Details as follows:

I have `datTable` contain proportion data under two factor `site` (four levels: A, B, C, D) and `treatment`(two levels: control and treated). Specifically, I want to do a pair-wise test among all the `site` under each same `treatment` (e.g. control-A VS. control-B, control-A VS.control-C, treated-A VS.treated-C, etc.), while excludes comparisons between different `sites` and different `treatments`(e.g., pairs such as control-A VS. treated-B, control-B VS. treated-C).

The data looks like this:

```
> datTable
   site treatment proportion
     A   control  0.5000000
     A   control  0.4444444
     A   treated  0.1000000
     A   treated  0.4000000
     B   control  0.4444444
     B   control  0.4782609
     B   treated  0.0500000
     B   treated  0.3000000
     C   control  0.3214286
     C   control  0.4705882
     C   treated  0.1200000
     C   treated  0.4000000
     D   control  0.3928571
     D   control  0.4782609
     D   treated  0.4000000
     D   treated  0.4100000
```

I did a two-way ANOVA (also not sure whether to use within subject `site/treatment` or between subject `site*treatment`...), and summarised the results.

```
  m1 <- aov(proportion~site*treatment,data=datTable) # Or should I use 'site/treatment'?
```

Then my `summary(m1)` gave me the following:

```
> summary(m1)
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
site            3 0.02548 0.00849   0.513 0.6845  
treatment       1 0.11395 0.11395   6.886 0.0305 *
site:treatment  3 0.03686 0.01229   0.742 0.5561  
Residuals       8 0.13239 0.01655
```

Next step is to use `TukeyHSD` post-hoc test to see actually which pair caused the `*` significance in `site` factor.

```
> TukeyHSD(m1)
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = proportion ~ site * treatment, data = datTable)

$site
            diff        lwr       upr     p adj
B-A -0.042934783 -0.3342280 0.2483585 0.9631797
C-A -0.033106909 -0.3244002 0.2581863 0.9823452
D-A  0.059168392 -0.2321249 0.3504616 0.9124774
C-B  0.009827873 -0.2814654 0.3011211 0.9995090
D-B  0.102103175 -0.1891901 0.3933964 0.6869754
D-C  0.092275301 -0.1990179 0.3835685 0.7461309

$treatment
                      diff        lwr         upr     p adj
treated-control -0.1687856 -0.3171079 -0.02046328 0.0304535

$`site:treatment`
                            diff        lwr       upr     p adj
B:control-A:control -0.010869565 -0.5199109 0.4981718 1.0000000
C:control-A:control -0.076213819 -0.5852551 0.4328275 0.9979611
D:control-A:control -0.036663216 -0.5457045 0.4723781 0.9999828
A:treated-A:control -0.222222222 -0.7312635 0.2868191 0.6749021
B:treated-A:control -0.297222222 -0.8062635 0.2118191 0.3863364  # Not wanted
C:treated-A:control -0.212222222 -0.7212635 0.2968191 0.7154690  # Not wanted
D:treated-A:control -0.067222222 -0.5762635 0.4418191 0.9990671  # Not wanted
C:control-B:control -0.065344254 -0.5743856 0.4436971 0.9992203
D:control-B:control -0.025793651 -0.5348350 0.4832477 0.9999985
A:treated-B:control -0.211352657 -0.7203940 0.2976887 0.7189552  # Not wanted
B:treated-B:control -0.286352657 -0.7953940 0.2226887 0.4233804  # Not wanted
C:treated-B:control -0.201352657 -0.7103940 0.3076887 0.7583437  # Not wanted
D:treated-B:control -0.056352657 -0.5653940 0.4526887 0.9996991
D:control-C:control  0.039550603 -0.4694907 0.5485919 0.9999713
A:treated-C:control -0.146008403 -0.6550497 0.3630329 0.9304819  # Not wanted
B:treated-C:control -0.221008403 -0.7300497 0.2880329 0.6798628  # Not wanted
C:treated-C:control -0.136008403 -0.6450497 0.3730329 0.9499131 
D:treated-C:control  0.008991597 -0.5000497 0.5180329 1.0000000  # Not wanted
A:treated-D:control -0.185559006 -0.6946003 0.3234823 0.8168230  # Not wanted
B:treated-D:control -0.260559006 -0.7696003 0.2484823 0.5194129  # Not wanted
C:treated-D:control -0.175559006 -0.6846003 0.3334823 0.8505865  # Not wanted
D:treated-D:control -0.030559006 -0.5396003 0.4784823 0.9999950  
B:treated-A:treated -0.075000000 -0.5840413 0.4340413 0.9981528
C:treated-A:treated  0.010000000 -0.4990413 0.5190413 1.0000000
D:treated-A:treated  0.155000000 -0.3540413 0.6640413 0.9096378
C:treated-B:treated  0.085000000 -0.4240413 0.5940413 0.9960560
D:treated-B:treated  0.230000000 -0.2790413 0.7390413 0.6429921
D:treated-C:treated  0.145000000 -0.3640413 0.6540413 0.9326207
```

However, there are some pairs I don't want to be included in the two-way ANOVA which I preformed, specified as `# not wanted`.

Is there any way that I can tweak the `aov` or `TukeyHSD` function to exclude those possibilities ('not wanted' ones) I listed above? I could easily select the significant entires that I am interested (with `*`) from the long list produced from `TukeyHSD`. But I don't want my result from anova to be biased by those! (It happens in the real data that the significance actually caused by those unwanted pairs!)

NB: You might have noticed that the `site:treatment` post-hoc tests doesn't show any significance, this is because I only selected a small sample from the original data.